# How to clip table view cell to view above

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios8

I have custom `tableViewCell` and `View` above it in `tableView`. After taping on button views height increase and cover cell's view. How to clip cell to bottom of view for changing position of cell and don't allow view to cover cell?

I tried to override `setFrame:` method in my cell. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the view above the cells is a table header view, you should reset that view as the header after you increase its size. So, if you're view was called myHeader, you would do this after changing the size ,

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeader;
```

Comment: No it is not a table header view, it is custom uiview. Firstly I add this view to the table view in a storyboard, then my cell. If I set some height in the xcode inspector, it displays correctly - the cell under the view without covering. But if I start change the frame of the view programmaticaly (f.e. after taping button) it increase over the cell.

Comment: Well, a table header view is a custom view. If you add a view to a table view, then even if it's not formally a table header view, it acts like one (that is, it scrolls with the table). Did you try my solution? You can also try setting it to be the table header view before the size change (in addition to afterwards).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much for your explanation! My iOS understanding improved.